# SQL multiple repeated string concatenation

Tags: sql

Can I simplify this query to make only one concatenation?

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE CONCAT(foo.bar, foo.baz) LIKE %test1% OR CONCAT(foo.bar, foo.baz) LIKE %test2%
```

I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the Concatenation in the SELECT

```
SELECT CONCAT(foo.bar, foo.baz) as newString 
FROM foo 
WHERE newString LIKE %test1% OR newString LIKE %test2%`
```

Answer (score 0):

It Must Work

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE CONCAT(foo.bar, foo.baz) LIKE %Concat(test1,test2)%
```

The idea is concat the like part